# jQuery animation fails in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

This problem is hard to explain, so I'll provide the code first and then, while describing the problem the best I can, I'll assume that you've compared the result in Firefox and any other browser.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/MEckv/ (click on the big box to start)

For some reason it seems like the boxes' left position are reset before they pop up, making it feel like they're just looping at the left side while the right box just changes color. This issue doesn't occur in Firefox, though.

Have I done something crazy in the code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks to be some strange positioning problem : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MEckv/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're specifying `right: 0px;` then trying to animate to a specific `left`. Apparently Firefox knows how to handle that, but other browsers don't seem to.

The solution is to convert your `left` constants to `right` ones **or** find the actual `left` values (using **jQuery**'s `.offset().left`) and style your boxes with them so that the browser knows how to animate (only the second method seemed to work perfectly). Here's a working little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/MEckv/51/).

I hope that helped!

Comment: @lvarska I've updated my answer with another method which works perfectly.

Comment: Ah! In my scenario I'll allways know the size of the boxes, so I simply changed to left instead of right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I already have a similar problem. It seems that Firefox sets left, top, etc., properties to 0 when they are not present and we use them, for example, to animate `left: 100` to `left: 0` or to compare some draggable div `top` to another div (where top was not specified). So, just try to set default values do left, top, etc., when you need to use them. It seems that we cannot assume that these values will initialized with default values (like 0) in other browsers than Firefox.